# How to duplicate a source XML file and append in the output a progressive number to predefined attributes?

Tags: xml, regex, bash, shell

I have an XML file which contains a series of Groups, e.g.

```
   <Group id="CB1391262521L-10816-1390650339-936236343" name="This Speed" color="#FFFFFF">
                <Topology>
                    <TopologyRect cylinderHor="false" hcount="1" cylinderVert="false" vcount="1"/>
                </Topology>
                <Name="test">
                    <Parameter value="1" name="ssd"/>
                    <Parameter value="1" name="amp"/>
                </Name>
                <Note></Note>
                <DiagramIcon width="50" x="89" y="392" height="50"/>
</Group>
<Group id="L-14827-1391619839-708665346" name="Angle" color="#FFFFFF">
                <Topology>
                    <TopologyRect cylinderHor="false" hcount="1" cylinderVert="false" vcount="2"/>
                </Topology>
                <Name="test">
                    <Parameter value="3" name="ssd"/>
                    <Parameter value="2" name="amp"/>
                </Name>
                <Note></Note>
                <DiagramIcon width="50" x="89" y="392" height="50"/>
</Group>
```

and connections, e.g.

```
<Connection target="CB1391262521L-10816-1390650339-936236343" type="excitatory" id="L-22494-1391265621-2060625361-1" source="L-14827-1391619839-708665346" name="Connection Reflex->M">
            <Pattern></Pattern>
</Connection>
```

I would like to make a unix shell script (using for example grep) that duplicates this files N times but for each copy created appends the string -01, -02 and so on (depending on N) to all the values contained in the `id`, `target` and `source` attributes of any tag in the XML file (Group, Connection, and others).
The script should have as parameters the orginal .xml file and the number of copies required, e.g.

```
myScript.py OriginalFile.xml 5
```

Where 5 is the number of copies, the output of the script produces 5 .xml files where the first file has -01 appendend to all the values contained in the id, target and source attributes, the second file will have -02 etc...

I think it's a regex search and replace, ant there is no need to parse the original XML file in Python, but simply read it line by line as a normal text file.

Comment: Do you need the code specifically in python ? This can be achieved using unix tools as well.

Comment: well, not necessarily python. A unix shell script that uses grep and a for cycle could be fine. Were this the case I will change the question's title so that we make it reflect the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

xml=$1
n=$2
for i in $(seq $n)
do
  i=$(printf "%02s" $i)
  sed -r "s/((id|target|source)=\"[^\"]+[0-9])/\1-$i/g" $xml > $i.xml
done
```

#### how to run

```
myScript.sh OriginalFile.xml 5
```

then you will get 5 xml files: `01.xml, 02.xml, etc.`

Comment: it works thanks. I commented `i=$(printf "%02s" $i)` cause I didn't need a space before the suffix (e.g. id="475839" -> id="475839-1" and not id="475839 -1")

Comment: I updated the sed command, now it can handle the space issue. You can still keep the `printf` command, if you need leading zero.

Answer (score 1):

Python Solution:

```
import re    
n=5    
with open("source.xml","r") as source:
    xml = source.read()

for i in range(n):
    with open("out-%d.xml" % i,"w") as target:
        modxml = re.sub(r'(id|target|source)="([^"]*)"',r'\1="\2-%d"' % i,xml)
        target.write(modxml)
```